# How do I get the title UILabel of a UIViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel

The following does not work

```
UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView;
```

OR

```
UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView;
```

Both return nil.

Yes, the title in question is in the navigation bar. The objective is simple: **I want the UILabel**. Can that be done?

**UPDATE**

**One** of the reasons I needed the UILabel is so that I could grab its width after I fill it with text, which would essentially tell me the max width of the label (basically a device agnostic way of measuring: whether iPad, iPhone, etc).

Comment: The `titleView` is `nil` unless you specifically set a custom `titleView`.

Comment: Yes, I already set the title in the storyboard.

Comment: You can assign a UILabel to `self.navigationItem.titleView`, then do what you want on this UILabel.

Comment: @meda your result works (to be fair), but the resulting `titleLabel` throws an exception on lines such as `titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 16.0f]`. Whereas a normal UILabel would not: throw an exception. (I know because I tested it).

Comment: @learner what exception you get and are you calling this in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @meda `self.title` is a property of type `NSString`. Don't you think casting it to `UILabel` will cause some problems ?

Comment: @meda self.title returns an instance of `NSString`, not `UILabel`, so what you're suggesting is impossible.

Comment: You guys have a valid point I removed it

Comment: @meda the exception is `-[__NSCFString setFont:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17808f050`. And it does not matter if I call it from `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @learner How did you set the title in the storyboard? Did you actually assign a custom view to the `titleView` property or did you simply enter some text into the "title" value? Big difference.

Comment: @learner setting the title of the view controller will not set the `titleView`. It's a separate property. I don't actually think you can set the `titleView` from a storyboard. You have to do it in code.

Comment: @Dan, actually, you can set the titleView in the storyboard. If you drag a UIView onto the navigation bar, it will be added as the title view (you will see it resize and center itself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer: You can't. `UINavigationBar` 's internals handle the display of a `UIViewController`'s title. The `titleView` property of `UINavigationItem` is used for other purposes.

The long answer

Look at `UINavigationBar.h` and get a rough understanding of how they both work together. - You'll quickly see why the titleView has nothing to do with a viewController's title.

`UINavigationItem` is the dataSource for a `UINavigationBar`.
It holds the barButtonItems, the title and the titleView for each `UIViewController`.
Look at the `UIViewController (UINavigationControllerItem)` category defined in `UINavigationController.h` there is a good explanation in the comments there.

The `UINavigationBar` on the other hand is 'simply' displaying the content of `UINavigationItems`.
When you push a viewController onto the stack of a navigationController, the navigationController implicitly calls `UINavigationBar: pushNavigationItem:animated:` on its navigationBar, sending the `UINavigationItem` of the viewController you are pushing.

I see you have the same misconception that i had when i started digging into UINavigationControllers:

The fact that you can write things like `UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView;` without any warning is very misleading

`UINavigationController` does not have a `UINavigationItem`. It will never have.
This is because a navigationController will never be contained inside another navigationController. (If you try to build this containment in IB it will give you a warning i think !?) The reason you can call `self.navigationController.navigationItem` is that the category i mentioned above is giving EVERY `UIViewController` a `UINavigationItem` property. `UINavigationController` in turn IS a `UIViewController` and thus receives the property from the category within its own implementation. - That's very confusing!

I assume you want to grab a reference to the `titleLabel` (even though you can't !), because you want to set the font or the textcolor of the title. If so, you can do these things through `UINavigationBar: setTitleTextAttributes:`.

If you want to use a complete custom titleView, you are better off creating a `UILabel` and assigning it to the `titleView` property of the `UINavigationItem`

Comment: This is a lot of information. Thank you for it. One of the reasons I needed the UILabel is so that I could grab its width after I fill it with text, which would essentially tell me the max width of the label. I took long with a reply because I have been trying all sorts of things. Do you know how I might still accomplish this?

Comment: In this case you might simply create an `UILabel`, set the text and assign the label as the titleView (`self.navigationItem setTitleView:`). After this assignment, the navigationBar will position ( & resize if needed) the label. So when you get the label's frame AFTER it has been set as the titleView, the frame.size.width will give you the width of the label. - Note that you may have to call `sizeToFit` on the label at some point, but as far as i can remember, that should not be necessary ;)

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
- (UILabel *)getNavBarTitleLabel
{
    UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    if (!navBar) { return nil; }

    for (UIView *subview in navBar.subviews) {
        for (UIView *subSubview in subview.subviews) {
            if ([subSubview isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                // consider adding more checks to verify that this UILabel is indeed the title label before returning it
                // for example, if you know what the text should be you can compare the strings
                return (UILabel*)subSubview;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```